# Creating an HTML to XHTML parser: Where do I get a full list of differences between the two languages?

Tags: html, xhtml

Suppose I want to write an HTML->XHTML parser. Where can I find a full list of differences between the two languages, so that I don't miss anything? (I understand this program amounts to an already-been-solved problem, but I'm doing it for personal challenge.)

Comment: I happen to have a list of differences on my own site, [here](http://strictquirks.nl/filetypes/htmlvsxhtml.html), but I'm not sure if that helps in creating a parser.